# Can't get response from the published API in WSO2am-1.7.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to subscribe a published API in WSO2am-1.7.0 but it gives no response. I have published a restful client of type GET. I am testing this in the API console of the WSO2AM by passing the values.The result should show me a JSON output which I get when hitting the restful client url in the browser.Even I tried out the example 'Find Tweets', that does not work too.

Answer (score 0):

User has to enable CORS configuration in the `api-manager.xml` to try the swagger client. Check [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Adding+Documentation+Using+Swagger) for more
Eg:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
<!-Configuration to enable/disable sending CORS headers from the Gateway->
   <Enabled>true</Enabled>
<!--The value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Default values are
API Store addresses, which is needed for swagger to function.-->
   <Access-Control-Allow-Origin>http://10.100.1.35:9763, https://10.100.1.35:9443</Access-Control-Allow-Origin>
<!-Configure Access-Control-Allow-Headers->
   <Access-Control-Allow-Headers>authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type</Access-Control-Allow-Headers>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: @Abhimaran, I did this change and followed the doc as well, but still it does not work for me. I create the API, make the changes in the `api-manager.xml` file. I subscribe to the API and as I try to test it through the APIConsole tab, providing the query parameters, enter the `Consumer Key` and click on `Try it out!` button, the operation simply goes on and on. No errors in the wso2 console.

Comment: You might be able to check the error by checking the browser's console (use firebug or similar). You might be able to see why the requests are not going to the AM from the browser

Comment: @user1662039 : Was your backend is HTTP or HTTPS? And You are accessing API Store through HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: @Abhimaran, I was able to get the response in the wso2 Rest client with changes I had to do in the `identity.xml`  `<RequestTokenUrl>`,`<AccessTokenUrl>`,`<AuthorizeUrl>` as well as the `_AuthorizeAPI_.xml`,`_RevokeAPI_.xml`,`_TokenAPI_` file but the same does not work in the WSO2 API console `Try it out`. Does even that need some changes in some files?